# how to generate a trajectory data from PCL

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all.

I wonder if you know how to generate a trajectory like this
[image: image description]

We read data from PCL to detect a flat surface and then generate a trajectory. Assuming we know the flat surface and its coordiante. I wonder if you could give me some suggestions, or a link to begin with?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265815/how-to-generate-a-trajectory-data-from-pcl/) by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at Godel (that's where the image is from, is it not?): [ros-industrial-consortium/godel](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/godel).

In particular the `godel_process_path_generation` and `path_planning_plugins`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-11**:
I know Godel and I'm sure that's the origin. My question is more like how does this code work, like a tutorial  or example of relevant trajectory generation.

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-11**:
It would really help me and I think many others. I know it uses open voronoi but I would really appreciate if I can have access to an example or anything.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-12**:
This i going to sound a bit harsh, but Godel *is* the example. Perhaps you could ask the developers over at `ros-industrial-consortium/godel` whether they have a more stand-alone example for you.

re: openvoronoi: know that that was only used in the *previous* version. The current version ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-12**:
.. does not use that anymore.

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-12**:
Thank you for your reply. May I know what they use right now?